# How do I create this arch in the middle of a cube?

Tags: modeling

Also, are there any techniques to do these kind of shapes in Blender?

[image]

Edit: Second part of this Q was removed. It has a new thread [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184379/how-do-i-indent-into-a-cube-to-get-such-curvature)

Comment: I couldn't picture what the arc you build has to do with the roof in the images above. Can you clarify?

Comment: no both are totally different images! In my model, I generally have to do such kind of shapes and I have trouble doing them hence put it up for reference. I am searching for an easy method to do it. only if the edges could be magically turned into curves so i could dip them, my life would be so much better

Comment: Blender has build in addons like Archipack and Archimesh and also Extra Curve addon can generate some arch type of shape. It really depence what specificaly you need to achieve. I'm not sure what do you mean edges to curves. You can Convert Mesh to Curve, but it depence what exactly you need to result with. If answers doesnt covers your Q edit your Q with more mockups.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the *Array* modifier with an *Object Offset*:

- Create a 8 vertex circle.

[image]

- Only keep 1/8, create an empty at the same point as its origin.

[image]

- Give your circle an *Array* modifier, *Count* > 8, deactivate *Relative Offset*, activate *Object Offset*, choose the empty as object, rotate the empty 45° on the Z axis.

[image]

- Model the object.

[image]

- Extrude it down, flatten the bottom with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Since others started to react to my oftopic comment here, I asked them to delete comments and move to chat to keep your answer clean. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I would say possible with three modifiers.

- create a segment
  (circle 8 sides, fill triangulate, keep 1/8)
- add **Solidify modifier** (to get hight)
- add *Sphere*
- select segment add **Boolean modifier** > *Difference* (object Sphere)
- add *Empty*, rotate 45°on Z axis
- select segment add **Array modifier** > Count 8 / Object offset ON - Empty

[image]
[image]

Tips:

- by moving and scaling Sphere you can shape curvature of segment
- to get nice topology following roof shape, direct top of sphere to center of segment

[image]

Comment: vklidu, our responses are slightly different, it would be worth if you gave a more detailed answer

Comment: @moonboots ok you got me :) I was ready to delete it, since your version was even better with topo, at the end I compensate this handicap a bit with Sphere rotation. BTW still one of us could spent time with another Q :) Cheers