# how do i indent into a cube to get such curvature

Tags: modeling

[image]

how do i create the above arch without those shabby polygons formations so its easy for UV unwrapping

Comment: is it a flat mesh?

Answer (score 3):

Just to have it all in one place, *Proportional editing* works well too.

Set Falloff > *Sphere* and adjust size to your needs.

[image]

Comment: yes of course, it would be good to be able to create our own falloff though

Comment: Oh that would be one sweet feature :).

Comment: thanks that helped a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You could start from a circle, delete the bottom half, stretch on the Z axis, extrude up and flatten on the Z axis with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. To give it depth, extrude on the Y axis.

[image]

You could also do it with the *Curve* tool: Create a plane, subdivide it, select the 2 extremity vertices and the central vertex, right click (context menu) > *LoopTools > Curve*.

[image]

It will also work if you start with a cube.

[image]