# Creating an irregular array for these rooftop tiles

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to create this pattern of rooftop tiles I saw while travelling, I'm pretty new to Blender so I'm trying to work this out using two arrays but I'm not quite getting there.

This is what I got so far

[image]

Are there certain methods I could use to achieve this pattern? Since they also have an offset of 50% on the x-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just offset it on multiple axis at once.

1. One Array modifier with X offset
2. Second Array modifier with X, Y and Z offset (you can also add start/end caps)
3. Third Array modifier to repeat this result

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! I guess filling in the empty gaps left and right is something the modifier isn't capable of doing? This helps me a lot thanks.

Comment: I just noticed you almost got it right in your screenshot :). Anyways, glad to be of help.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, how did you create the tile shape? I created a circle, cut away 75% and then added a plane to that mesh and connected the vertices, Is there an easier way to create this rounded rectangle?

Comment: @MiguelStevens I used proportional editing for the curved end, similar [to this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/184385/78972).